# Can't clear text selection from textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## Problem:

I have multiple `textarea`s that can be navigated using arrow keys. The `textarea`s are focused using `ref.focus()`.

When the `textarea`s are focused this way, the text selection is not cleared?

## Screenshot

[image]

## Expect

The text selection in the second `textarea` should be cleared when the first is clicked, or when the second `textarea` is focused again.

## Code

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export const Test = () => {
  const [editingBlock, setEditingBlock] = useState<Number | null>(null);
  const textArea1Ref = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement | null>(null);
  const textArea2Ref = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // set 1 focus
    if (editingBlock === 1 && textArea1Ref.current) {
      textArea1Ref.current.focus();

      // blur 2
      if (textArea2Ref.current) {
        textArea2Ref.current.blur();
      }

      // set 2 focus
    } else if (editingBlock === 2 && textArea2Ref.current) {
      textArea2Ref.current.focus();

      // blur 1
      if (textArea1Ref.current) {
        textArea1Ref.current.blur();
      }
    }
  }, [editingBlock]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <textarea
          ref={textArea1Ref}
          value={"a really long string"}
          onBlur={(e) => setEditingBlock(null)}
          onKeyDown={(e) => {
            if (e.key === "ArrowDown") setEditingBlock(2);
          }}
          onClick={(e) => setEditingBlock(1)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <textarea
          ref={textArea2Ref}
          value={"a really long string"}
          onBlur={(e) => {
            if (window.getSelection()) {
              window.getSelection()!.removeAllRanges(); // doesn't work
            }
            setEditingBlock(null);
          }}
          onClick={(e) => setEditingBlock(2)}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Hacky solution

I still don't fully understand why this is happening, but found a workaround solution for now:

In the `textarea`'s `onBlur` callback, simply use the following code:

```js
if (textArea2Ref.current) {
    // if there's a range selection
    if (textArea2Ref.current.selectionStart !== textArea2Ref.current.selectionEnd) {
        // reset the range
        textArea2Ref.current.selectionStart = textArea2Ref.current.selectionEnd;

        // blur the textarea again, because setting the selection focuses it?
        textArea2Ref.current.blur();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## The value will always be the same

You have set the value with a string, this will never change since it's a static value in the field.

If you would like to make the field changeable use some state, reducer or library to handle fields.

Here's an example

```
const [textArea1, setTextArea1] = useState<string>('');
...
return (
  ...
  <textarea
     ref={textArea1Ref}
     value={textArea1}
     onChange={(event) => setTextArea1(event.target.value)}
  />
  ...
)
```

To clear the field on blur you just need fire `setTextArea1('')`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question, maybe I wasn’t clear enough. But I’m trying to clear the **selection** (highlight), not the text itself. The strings are static because that is irrelevant.

Comment: ah, sorry, then yes, I did misunderstand. let me take another look.